# mysqli_fetch_array only displays the first result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I struggled all day to display the results of an SQL query using PHP.
I have a table in the database named coins with the following columns:
- `nr_unic` (which is the index);
- `rank`;
- `name`;
- `symbol`;
- `price_usd`;
- `price_btc`;
What I need to do is to fetch the values of each coin (from the `name` field) and display the `symbol`, `price_usd`, `price_btc`, and `rank`. The piece of code which contains the query I am running and trying to display the values is:

```
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // SQL QUERY
    $sql= "SELECT rank, name, symbol, price_usd, price_btc, 24h_volume_usd FROM coins WHERE rank BETWEEN 1 AND 10 ORDER BY nr_unic DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $rows[] =  $row['name'] . " " . $row['price_usd'] . " " . $row['symbol'] . " " . $row['rank'];
    foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    }
    }
    mysqli_free_result ($result);
    }
```

Thank you!

**LATER EDIT**
Following @Máté Solymosi indications I managed updated the code and to display the results. The problem now is they are getting duplicated: I get the first coin, then the first and the second, then the first, second and third... and so on.
**The code I use was updated**

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_row  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['price_usd'] . " " . $row['symbol'] . " " . $row['rank'];
    }  remove return.

Comment: Make sure you know purpose of `return` statement.

Comment: You are doing "return" within the loop, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I also tried to use mysqli_fetch_row with `echo` instead of `return` but the result is the same. However I am using this inside an WordPress website for which I want to make a shortcode to run this code. That's why I used `return` in the first place.

Comment: You are running a `foreach` loop *inside* a `while` loop, this is causing your repetition. Perhaps a good time to read the manual on what [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [**while**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement in your `while` loop causes the function to terminate immediately, returning just the first row. Instead, you should collect the results in an array and return the array at the end:

```
$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  $rows[] = $row['name'] . " " . // ...
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
return $rows;
```

Comment: I run this code in a wordpress function (need to create a shortcode) and that's why I need to use `return` instead of `echo`. Also when I use the code you provided I still get the values for one coin only...

Comment: That makes sense. I assumed this was part of a function, otherwise `return` would not work at all.

Comment: Do you have any other method that I could try?

Comment: Didn't this work? What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: `$rows` is now an array, so you will have to loop over it when displaying it.

Comment: Ok so inside the `while loop` I ran the following code: `foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
 return $value;
}`  and still returns me only one result....

Comment: You made the same mistake in your `foreach` loop: the `return` there prematurely ends the execution of the loop (and the function), so you only get the first value returned.

Comment: Your answer, in the end, helped me to solve the issue!